# How to write a sql query to get only whose ID is 100000004 from the below 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

my requirement is to display FriendUserID, FriendUserName, PicID, Image from the below tables and whose ID is 100000004

Note: I need to display my friend data not mine My UserID is : 100000004

[image: Friend List Table]

[image: User Table]

[image: Picture Table]

Edit: Code from comments:

```
SELECT
    Name = (u.firstname + u.lastname),
    fl.frienduserid,
    pp.picid,
    pp.image
FROM profilepic pp
INNER JOIN users u
    ON pp.userid = u.userid
INNER JOIN friendlist fl
    ON fl.frienduserid = u.userid
WHERE fl.userid = @uid
OR fl.frienduserid = '100000004'
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I doubt you are using three distinct versions of SQL Server, so I removed the extraneous tags.  Feel free to add back the tag for the version you are actually using.

Comment: this is my query select  Name=(u.firstname+u.lastname),fl.frienduserid,pp.picid,pp.image from profilepic pp inner join users u on pp.userid=u.userid 
inner join friendlist fl on fl.frienduserid=u.userid where fl.userid=@uid or fl.frienduserid='100000004'

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your quite obscure question,

`SELECT
    Name = (fl.firstname + fl.lastname),
    fl.frienduserid,
    pp.picid,
    pp.image
FROM users u
    INNER JOIN friendlist fl
    ON u.userid = fl.frienduserid
        INNER JOIN profilepic pp
        ON pp.userid = fl.userid
WHERE u.userid = '100000004'`

Answer (score 0):

guy thank you very much for your response, finally i got the solution

```
create procedure proc_DisplayAllFriendData(@uid bigint)
as begin
--declare @uid bigint
--set @uid = '100000004'
select u.userid as frienduserid, Name=(u.firstname+u.lastname),pp.picid,pp.image from profilepic pp inner join users u on u.userid=pp.userid where u.userid in(
select 
      frienduserid 
      from(
select userid,frienduserid from friendlist where userid=@uid and ustatusid='4'
Union all
select frienduserid,userid from friendlist where frienduserid=@uid and frndstatusid='4')fl)
end
```